# Changed sitecore template inheritance, all layouts broken

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

After changing the inheritance structure of a template I seem to have broken every layout on the entire site.

In short we had two content page templates in two different locations. I basically changed templates inheriting from /bad path/Content Page to /good path/content page.

I've set breakpoints in the sublayouts, but basically anything set up in the page editor using placeholders isn't displaying correctly, and the code isn't even getting hit.

*** UPDATE ***
Here is an interesting warning in the log file
3176 09:05:52 WARN  Long running operation: renderContentEditor pipeline[id={xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}]

Thanks

Comment: stupid question but does `/good path/content page` have the same presentation settings defined for it's standard values item that `/bad path/Content Page` has?

Comment: I don't think it is stupid, the standard values actually are slightly different for the presentation setting, but I have the presentation settings specifically set, how does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Are you saying you have set presentation settings directly on the content items or are they inheriting from the standard values item for `/good path/Content Page`?. If you pick one item that currently isn't displaying properly. Does it's presentation settings look correct?

Comment: yes, i did set it on the items directly, I can't change the standard values.  They actually do look correct on each individual item, just nothing is showing up.  If I reset them exactly the same, it shows up.  If I change the inheritance back, it's still broken.  Very weird.

Comment: if it displays correctly when you reset to standard values then there must be some differences between that and the presentation settings you have defined directly on the items. If you are working against a web db then make sure you publish and double check by going to the web db that it looks as expected

Comment: yeah, it is more like when I individually reset to what it previously was.  Very weird, but not a ton of content I guess

Comment: Are your placeholders defined the same between both the templates? i.e. if your placeholder is `main-content` is that the same key used in both presentation settings?

Comment: the placeholders are set on the layout, the template change shouldn't affect that, unless I'm mistaken, which is very possible given the problem I've created myself

Comment: This is what I see in the log file... Long running operation: renderContentEditor pipeline[id={xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}]

Answer (score 0):

If your presentation details are set on individual items and not being inherited from the template, a change of template would not generally affect the placeholder settings of the item. It should retain all of its existing item-specific presentation details.

That being said, I would recommend double-checking the items to make sure they are not inheriting from the template and have their own override value (check the Layout field in the Content Editor to see if it says "Standard Values" next to the field name)

The other part of this could be the field access. You mentioned you changed templates inheriting from one content page to another. If your code references fields by ID, your different templates will have different ID values for the same field. So if your "content page" template has a "Title" field, it will not get the data from the "Title" field of your other "Content Page" template. This could cause a lot of errors as you may be depending on the presence of a field. This would usually lead to .NET errors in many cases, however.